# Compile GLobjects

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, build

I'm new to GLobjects and I have difficulties when compiling it.

my document structure:

[image]

In the main.cpp, I just use a simple `#include<iostream> int main(){return 0;}` as example.

In CMakeLists.txt, I wrote :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)
project(globject)
add_subdirectory(glm)
add_subdirectory(globjects)
add_executable(globject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(globject glm globjects)
```

The glm and globjects files contains the two libraries.
When I run cmake. in build, I got this error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glm" with any of
  the following names:    
    glmConfig.cmake
    glm-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "glm" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "glm_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.
```

I tried a lot of ways to fix the problem but I got nowhere. what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you just unpack glm and globjects sources into these two directories?
I've never seen anyone use CMake in such way, I don't think it will work. Common way is to install glm and globjects into your system (`apt install libglm-dev libglobjects-dev`, this is Ubuntu I suppose?), then use `find_package` CMake command.

Comment: Thanks, the local installation on Ubuntu works for me,  but I want that my program could be directly downloaded and and compiled, so I need to include globjects as a submodule in my program.

Answer (score 0):

We only have to include the proper header files  , no linking and compiling necessary.
GLM can be downloaded from their website.
Copy the root directory of the header files into your includes folder .

https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html

Comment: Thanks, the real problem is globjects,  it looks for something called glmConfig.cmake when I build it.